# mySQL: use LIKE with SUBSTR in a query?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

How can I do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM .... WHERE wp_users.user_email LIKE '%SUBSTR(wp_callbacks.post_data, INSTR(wp_callbacks.post_data, 'payer_email')+19, 20)%'...
```

What I am trying to do is query a wp_callbacks table (that stores it in the format like s:11:"payer_email";s:18:"some.email@gmail.com" ...) and see if the actual email from wp_users matches that email from wp_callbacks table.

The problem is that I don't know how long the email itself is so I picked a random value (20) in SUBSTR call to grab the first 20 characters of the email itself and then I want to check if the user_email is LIKE '%...%' that value.

Ideas?

Comment: Why did you put the `SUBSTR` function inside the string and also what is with the extra `%`

Comment: That's just to show what I am trying to do... I am obviously not using the right syntax, and that's what I need help with. I need to do the LIKE with %...%, not the exact match, to see if the SUBSTR string is actually within the original email string (from wp_users.user_email).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about - not tried though

```
SELECT * 
FROM .... 
WHERE wp_users.user_email LIKE 
    CONCAT('%', 
    SUBSTR(wp_callbacks.post_data, INSTR(wp_callbacks.post_data, 'payer_email')+19, 20),
    '%');
```